# Discord.py: how to show dates in an embed like shown in discord message timestamps?

Tags: discord, discord.py, timestamp

I want to replicate this representation of time: [What I Want To Recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb5IB.png)

What I already have: [What I Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDTH9.png)

Code:

```
created = ctx.guild.created_at
embed.add_field(name = f"Created:", value = f"{created}", inline=False)
```

How can I recreate it?

Comment: You need the timestamp of `{created}` and then use a format of your choice. See https://r.3v.fi/discord-timestamps/ for some more help on which things can be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, discord uses epoch value to get time and the format to get it is `<t:{epoch value}:{mode}>`. To get the epoch value there is a function know as `timestamp()`.

So our new code will be :

```py
created = ctx.guild.created_at.timestamp()
embed.add_field(name ="created at:", value=f"<t:{created}:R>",......)
```

Comment: This did not work for me, but I got it working using this:

        created = ctx.guild.created_at.timestamp()
        embed.add_field(name = "Created:", value = f"<t:{int(created)}:R>")

Comment: yeah, i forgot that we cannot have special things in name field